# psycopg2 shows sensitive infromation in logs

Tags: python, postgresql, logging, psycopg2

I am currently connecting to db using psycopg2. If for example query fails I get error message that contains entire sql insert statement where sensitive information is.
Is there a way to configure psycopg2 so it will not show the sql statement or mask some fields?

Example:

`"ERROR", "message": "(psycopg2.errors.UniqueViolation) duplicate key value violates unique constraint \"pksa_account\"\nDETAIL:  Key (b_loadid, customer_account_number)=(xx, xxxx) already exists.\n\n[SQL: INSERT INTO ... ...`

Where after INSERT INTO are actual fields and values.

Comment: Where is this message showing up?

Comment: It's the same in db logs and application logs, so I assume that psycopg2 is just forwarding db logs to the application.

Answer (score 1):

We solved this problem using sqlalchemy to connect (which is using psycopg2 under the hood btw) that provides configuration option when creating engine: `hide_parameters = True` and that's all it took to resolve. Now we have pretty logs with parameters masked:

````
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(4) already exists.

[SQL: INSERT INTO xxx.xxx(id, loaddatetime) VALUES (%(id)s, %(loaddatetime)s)]
[SQL parameters hidden due to hide_parameters=True]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/13/gkpj)```
````